# H2OValueError: File ‪train_FD004.txt does not exist

Tags: python, h2o

hi guys so i'm currently trying to use h2o and encountering a problem for uploading the data

```
train = h2o.upload_file("‪train_FD004.txt")
test  = h2o.upload_file("test_FD004.txt")
train.set_names(input_file_column_names);
test.set_names(input_file_column_names);
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about H20, but generally that type of error,

> H2OValueError: File ‪train_FD004.txt does not exist

Means it cannot find the file you are trying to upload.

You should try:

1. Make sure you have typed the name of the file correctly, including spelling, white-space and extension.
2. Make sure the file is in the correct directory, whether that is the same directory as your program or whatever directory you're attempting to reference.

Comment: It can be hard to know what the "current" directory is, especially as it can be different for each of `h2o.import_file()` and `h2o.upload_file(), so I quickly found it was simpler to always give the full path to any data files.